# Is it good to use same color as accent and primary?

Tags: color, google-material-design

As title says , is it good idea to use same color as primary color and accent color in material design?

Comment: I would say the whole point of an accent color would be to differentiate between different aspects of a design and add contrast. So having only one main color would make this difficult. Possibly using different shades of the same color would be better. Check out https://color.adobe.com/ they have some great color palette tools to help create color schemes.

Comment: to be honest I dont 100% understand the question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

NO ! According to Material specs

Don't.

Don’t use the accent color for app bars or larger areas of color. Avoid using the same color for the floating action button and the background.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application

[image]

Comment: You may want to stress in image text or something that the image you show is undesireable

Comment: yes this is true. but there is many apps that designed against this rule and many of them is built by google! (like Gmail and Google+ app) . in some situations fab and actionbar haven't any Interference , maybe there is a exception in this situations...